# How to stream video with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I'm creating an app where i need to implement multiple live streams on different pages with PhoneGap and by using Framework7. How can I play the streams from a URL (I have .m3u8 and rtmp:// stream links), I tried with html5  but it doesn't work when i tested it. I'm thinking about using a plugin but I don't know which one works best and how to add it to the index.html file.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1017

The Adobe PhoneGap build is an awesome Tool for your PhoneGap/Cordova project.

Check it out.